# Discord.py Buttons doesn't work with Slash Commands

Tags: python, discord.py

I tried everything to get the Buttons work inside a Slash command but it doesn't work.
I am using the discord_slash libary for the slash commands
and
I am using the discord_components libary for the Buttons

It only works with embeds or normal messages without Buttons and It's gives this error:
`` An exception has occurred while executing command `jobs`: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get' ``
and here is a snipped from my code:

````
msg = await ctx.send(
            embed=a_dictionary["a"],
            components = [
                [Button(style=ButtonStyle.blue, label="◀️"),
                Button(style=ButtonStyle.blue, label="▶️"),
                Button(style=ButtonStyle.green, label="Get Job"),
                Button(style=ButtonStyle.red, label="Remove Job")
                ],
            ]
        )```
````

Comment: Irgnore the ```

Comment: Thats definitely no discord.py